# nginx полная изоляция приложения

Tags: php, nginx

### Что есть

- docker контейнер nginx с висящими портами host:81->contaner:80
- docker контейнер php-fpm с приложением которое коректно работает если
  **http_host** будет site.test:**80**
- nginx config

```
location ~ ^/index\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

### Что нужно

- Браузер должен заходить на site.test:**81** а php приложение должно
  видить запрос как site.test:**80**
- Если php вернет редирект, тоесть http location == site.test:**80**/admin то в браузер должно вернуться location == site.test:**81**/admin

### Обьяснение

Нужно тестировать сайт который умеет работать только на 80 порту, но при этом на одном компьютере нужно запустить несколько версий приложения. Есть желание усовершенствовать nginx конфиг так что бы сайт неподозревал подмены

### Что пробывал

`fastcgi_param  HTTP_HOST site.test;` но редиректы не работают коректно

Comment: Странно, что есть директива `proxy_redirect`, но нет `fastcgi_redirect`

Comment: В качестве костыля наверное можно написать промежуточный `server` блок в котором будет fastcgi, ходить в него `proxy_pass`-ом и применить `proxy_redirect`